# Why system calls are limited to C language as far as I see?

Tags: programming-languages, operating-systems

From my Operating System textbook, application and library interact with kernel by system calls.

But as far as I can see, Windows, OS X and Linux, we can only use C Language to post system calls.

That annoyed me when I want to optimize I/O in our Java application -- since I can't use system call directly, So I have to guess what system call requested by a Java API(Maybe I should read JVM source code? But I was worried that will take too much time to meet the deadline), then optimize I/O by my guessing.

Since then I got a question, why system calls are limited to C language, and why we can't do that in Python, Java and many other programming languages?

EDIT:

I know OS X, Windows and Linux all are implemented by C, but there is still a question:

If an OS is implemented by a certain programming language, we can only request system call by that programming language? What's the reason for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why not have a High Level Language based OS? Are Low Level Languages more efficient?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203024/why-not-have-a-high-level-language-based-os-are-low-level-languages-more-effici)

Comment: @gnat That's a good question, but I think there is a little difference between that question and mine. Could you please see my edit?

Comment: Not a line of C in sight (but quite a lot of inline assembly): https://github.com/kmcallister/syscall.rs

Comment: the question added in recent edit seems to have been asked brefore: [How do programming languages integrate with OS runtimes](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246601/how-do-programming-languages-integrate-with-os-runtimes)

Comment: On Windows applications should never syscall directly. You always call a usermode function that's provided by windows, which handles syscalling for you.

Comment: **Why do you ask?** Please *edit your question* to motivate it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Interesting. I had a question so I ask. I think the curiosity is my motivation. As a newbie of the programming world, I want to discuss my thoughts and questions with other programmers.

Comment: Actually system calls are limited to assembly language. The fact that C interfaces fairly nicely with assembly language, and Python does not, and Java does not, is Python's and Java's problem. Nothing to do with C.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> On Windows, OS X and Linux, we can only use C Language to post system calls.

Actually, this is wrong, at least for Linux.

The real [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) does not use the same [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) than C, as defined in the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). Details are of course processor specific (so let's focus on x86-64).

<sup>(I am not exactly sure of all the details here, you need to check; I've read about them several years ago...)</sup>

The actual system call uses a machine instruction like `SYSENTER` or `SYSCALL`, and passes the number of the system call (probably in `%eax`) and its arguments in various (well specified) processor registers. But it does not use the stack pointer at all. So you could (in your machine code) in principle make a system call without any stack, or with an invalid `%rsp` (e.g. set to nil). In contrast, calling C functions require a valid stack pointer (even if most arguments are passed in registers).

The actual system call uses a different return convention. If the *[carry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag) bit* is set, the system call has failed, and `%eax` contains the `errno` code. If the carry bit is cleared, the system call has succeeded, and `%rax` contains its result.

Therefore, some programming languages implementations can even avoid any C library. For example Scheme's [bones](http://www.call-with-current-continuation.org/bones/).  And you can code a program in assembler for Linux without using any `libc` and without using C calling conventions.

Hence, [C standard libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)' implementations need (for every system call), a tiny *wrapping* function. When you call in C the [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) "system call" function, you are actually calling a tiny wrapper.

The [Linux Assembler HowTo](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) is giving some details. Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). But you should also look into the source code of your Linux [kernel](http://kernel.org/) and your C standard library (e.g. [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) has very readable code).

> If an OS is implemented by a certain programming language, we can only request system call by that programming language?

This is wrong. The calling convention (using `SYSENTER` etc....) to the kernel is not the same as for C. You can code system calls in other ways.

Notice that on Linux, some low level utility functions are *not* system calls (which are *exhaustively* listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...); in particular [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) & [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) & DNS functions like [getaddrinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) etc are implemented by *several* system calls. See also [nsswitch.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html). And some system calls (e.g. [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)...) avoid the kernel overhead with [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) tricks.

See also [OSDev](http://osdev.org/) wiki.

> Why system calls are limited to C language, and why we can't do that in Python, Java and many other programming languages?

As I explained, systems calls are *not* limited to C. However, C is very convenient (as a [lingua franca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_franca) or portable assembler-like language). So most programming languages implementors are using it, and often provide some libraries calling system calls of the C standard library. Also standards like [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) are normalizing & defining "system" functions (e.g. [mmap](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mmap.html)) in terms of C code. Hence the programming language implementors have interest to code in C (his implementation is then likely to be *easily* [portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) to various Unix-like or POSIX-like systems ; in other words nearly the *same* C source code - e.g. of Lua or Guile or Ocaml - implementation is likely to work on various systems like MacOSX, Linux, FreeBSD, TrueOS and possibly even GNU Hurd). So [bones](http://www.call-with-current-continuation.org/bones/) is much harder to port from Linux to MacOSX or TrueOS than [guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile), even if they implement nearly the same programming language (some Scheme dialect).

> why we can't do that in Python, Java and many other programming languages?

In practice, all these language *implementations* (remember that a programming language is a *specification* written in some document; it is *not* a software) are using the `libc` to avoid portability hassles.

<sup>(IIRC on some *BSD systems system calls are passing arguments on the machine stack, unlike Linux; but I leave you to check that)</sup>

Read also [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Answer (score 5):

> But as far as I can see, Windows, OS X and Linux, we can only use C Language to post system calls.

The premise here isn't actually correct.  Ultimately, it's about making the processor execute the sequence of instructions that the kernel expects for a trap to happen.  Any language that can make those instructions happen can make a system call happen directly.  The [Rust example cited by Michał Politowski](https://github.com/kmcallister/syscall.rs) in the comments is a perfect example of this in action.

The system calls you're familiar with were written in C because it's the second-from-lowest common denominator in the system, just above assembly.  This gives developers a canned, portable, backed-by-a-known-standard implementation to call using the native linkage mechanism when they want a specific function such as `read(2)` or `ioctl(2)`.  Because this sort of thing has been a known quantity since the dawn of computing, almost every language offers facilities to call through to native object code, even some that that are interpreted or effectively interpreted.

> That annoyed me when I want to optimize I/O in our Java application -- since I can't use system call directly, So I have to guess what system call requested by a Java API...

Java was built this way on purpose:  you get the ability to run the same code anywhere at the expense of having a layer of abstraction between it and the processor.  You're not supposed go know or care how it happens.  Even so, Java has an escape hatch into the local system called the Java Native Interface.  JNI is a tacit admission that you can't do everything in paradise and sometimes have to venture out into the seamy underbelly of the rest of the system.

I would suggest that at least some of what you gain back making a native system call will be offset by going through JNI.  Benchmarking that against a pure Java solution for your I/O would be time well spent before committing to it.  I'd also suggest that if you knew ahead of time that your performance requirements were strict enough to require that kind of optimization, Java might not have been the right choice of language for the project.

Comment: Really thanks! Now I have one more question, where could I find the documentation for `the sequence of instructions that the kernel expects`, or any useful search engine keyword?

Comment: @Sayakiss: The answer would be different for every operating system (and even for different versions of one operating system). This is typically described in the operating system's API (on the level of C functions that you can call).

Comment: @Sayakiss The more important point is that the kind of optimization you're proposing is something that rarely has to be done.  To put it bluntly, unless you've done the measurements that identify a bottleneck between your application code and the actual performance of the I/O that can be attributed to the JVM, I think you're barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 2):

### They aren't

C++ and Delphi (among others) are perfectly happy to import the names of system calls and call them with no additional effort. C# has a language feature ([Marshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240804/marshalling-what-is-it-and-why-do-we-need-it)) that makes it look like it is doing the same, but actually does stuff on the interface.

They are instead limited to the [calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx) popularised by C. Also by convention they tend to be documented as if they were a C function declaration.